# What impact do genetic engineering techniques have on seed breeders?

Tags: genetics, crispr, seeds, vegetable, agriculture

In research of seed breeding, I'm trying to understand the impact of genetic engineering techniques like CRISPR (This is the main one as I understand) on traditional seed breeders. Through searching on the internet, I believe to have found the following two types of impact:

1. research: increased speed of detection which genes make for which vegetable trait. This is supposed to be used already by many breeders.
2. Growing: Reducing the breeding cycles by up to a factor 2, by early selection which plants are the good ones in the breeding process (I don't really understand how this would work)

So the main total impact of new breeding technologies would be the shortening of breeding cycles, putting increased pressure on fast innovation.

Am I missing any type of impact? Is CRISPR going to change seed breeding in a dramatic way? For instance, is there a way to take someone else his/her seed, then using crisper (in some way?) to immediately know which genes make up for the desired vegatable traits? Or some increased speed in which one could copy traits of other seeds? Also I'd like to know how the second point works: using CRISPR to reduce the breeding cycles for seeds.